# PHP POST request debugging

Tags: php, forms, post

**Context**

I have the following POST pipeline:

> index.php -> submit.php ->list/item/new/index.php

index.php has a normal form with an **action**="submit.php" property.
submit.php decides where to send the following post request by some logic based on the POST variable *content*.

The **problem** is that I haven't found a successful way to debug this pipeline. Somewhere, something is failing and I would appreciate a fresh pair of eyes.

**What I have tried**

- I have tried running list/item/new/index.php with dummy parameters through a regular GET request. DB updates successfully.
- I have tried running submit.php (below) with dummy parameters through a regular GET request. The value of $result is not FALSE, indicating the file_get_contents request was successful, but it's *value* is the **literal content** of list/new/index.php instead of the **generated content**, which I *expect* to be the result of

  echo $db->new($hash,$content) && $db->update_content_key($hash);

Here is submit.php

```
$url = 'list/new/index.php';
if($test){
    $content = $_GET["i"];
    $hash = $_GET["h"];
    }else{
    $content = $_POST["item"]["content"];
    $hash = $_POST["list"]["hash"];
    }
$data = array(
        'item'=>array('content' => $content),
        'list'=>array('hash' => $hash)
        );
$post_content = http_build_query($data);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($post_content) . "\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $post_content
        )
    );
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    echo "error";
    //commenting out for testing. should go back to index.php when it's done
    //header('Location: '.$root_folder_path.'list/?h='.$hash.'&f='.$result);
    }
else{
    var_dump($result);
    //commenting out for testing. should go back to index.php when it's done
    //header('Location: '.$root_folder_path.'list/?h='.$hash.'&f='.str_replace($root_folder_path,"\n",""));
    }
```

And here is list/item/new/index.php

```
$db = new sql($root_folder_path."connection_details.php");
if($test){
    $content = $_GET["i"];
    $hash = $_GET["h"];
    }else{
    $content = $_POST["item"]["content"];
    $hash = $_POST["list"]["hash"];
    }
// insert into DB, use preformatted queries to prevent sqlinjection
echo $db->new($hash,$content) && $db->update_content_key($hash);
```

The worst thing about this is that I don't know enough of PHP to effectively debug this (I actually had it working at some point today but I did not commit right then...).

All comments and suggestions are welcome. I appreciate your time.

Comment: What does the `$_POST` look like in the submit.php ( `var_dump($_POST)` at the beginning of the submit file )?

Comment: @NMoeini As expected. Here is the dump:
    `array (size=2)
      'item' => 
        array (size=1)
          'content' => string 'test' (length=4)
      'list' => 
        array (size=1)
          'hash' => string '47f563d25d9b5993bbf6b666dc512684f6806c60' 
    (length=40)`

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

I'm not sure what to call the error I was making (or what is actually going on behind the scenes) but it was the following:

on the POST request I was using

```
$url='list/item/new/index.php'
```

I used the whole url scheme:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/list/item/new/index.php';`
```